# How to read a variable inside a function of a class from another class?

Tags: typescript

i try to access a variable value inside a function of a class from another class, here is some code

```
export class ClassService  {
  myvar = 'text';
  public myfunc(){
    this.myvar = "New text"
  }
}
```

so i want to access the new value which is in this case "New Text",
i have tried this

```
export class AppComponent  {
  newclass = new ClassService()
  name = this.newclass.myvar;
}
```

but still i get only "text", am not sure what i have done wrong,
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `myfunc()` of class `ClassService` is never called. You should call it external or internal by a class constructor.

```
export class ClassService  {
  myvar = 'text';

  constructor() {
    this.myfunc();
  }

  public myfunc(){
    this.myvar = "New text"
  }
}
```

or external:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  newclass = new ClassService()
  newclass.myfunc();
  name = this.newclass.myvar;
}
```

Comment: Also, working with getters and setters would be clean.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i guess i did not represent my problem correctly (sorry for that) , myfunc() have a property 

  public myfunc(a){
      this.myvar = a
    }

Comment: If your method `myfunc` has parameter can just pass them. You could also use optional parameter with default values. (optional parameters are marked with questionmark like `myfunc(a?: string) {this.myvar = a}` or `myfunc(a = 'LOL') {...}`) You could also pass this param through the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You want to invoke the function first:

```
export class AppComponent {

  newclass = new ClassService();
  newclass.myfunc();

  const name = this.newclass.myvar;
}
```